# logs Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

Tags: reactjs, heroku

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.16.0...
       Using default npm version: 8.11.0
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       added 120 packages, and audited 121 packages in 8s
       
       15 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > newportfolio@0.1.0 heroku-postbuild
       > NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client
       
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.x" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.19
npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm ERR!     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"^0.1.14" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-scripts, react-toastify)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!   react-typical@"^0.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!     react-typical@"^0.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.u5EXI/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.u5EXI/_logs/2022-07-10T18_18_44_784Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is straightforward here:

```
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2

npm ERR! node_modules/react

npm ERR! react@"^17.0.2" from the root project

npm ERR! peer react@">=16.x" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.19

npm ERR! node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome

npm ERR! @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"^0.1.14" from the root project

npm ERR! 4 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-scripts, react-toastify)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3

npm ERR! node_modules/react-typical

npm ERR! react-typical@"^0.1.3" from the root project
```

Your `package.json` requires `react@"^17.0.2"` but `react-typical` requires `react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0"` ; so you have a conflict between the versions of React.

To solve this, try to update the version of your libraries. New versions can add compatibilities with new versions. If not, see if this library is necessary for your project.

**Edit**
react-typical does not require the last version of React. So, you have to fork this library to use the last version of React or you may simply drop this library. The last commit has been published in 2019, this library is maybe not longer maiained.

Comment: Hello, and thank you.from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-typical) I did `npm install --save react-typical` and now the error message is this.




/tmp/build_2c7a0b39/client/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:19

  throw err;

  ^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)

    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)

    at module.exports (/tmp/build_2c7a0b39/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)

... I can't show the whole logs.

Comment: Answer edited above